# Getting 'SSL certificate expired' error even after adding new certificate

Tags: kubernetes, ssl-certificate, kubernetes-secrets, k8s-serviceaccount

I have a namespace where multiple services are active on multiple pods. And the whole namespace has a unique secret where the ca-certificate is stored. So somehow while executing an input through my service I am getting SSL certificate expired. But my pipeline has updated certificate. So is it possible that through some other services deployment the ca-certificate is updated to the old one and which is impacting my service? If yes then how can I identify that affecting service pod which has accidentally updated the old certificate on secret. And how can I avoid this risk in future?

I have verified expiry date of SSL certificate which I have added in my pipeline. Everything is upto date.

Comment: Wild guess: your pods do not handle hot reloading of secrets, they need to be restarted.